# How can I get the same data structure as FileReader API manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, base64, filereader

I don't quite understand what is happening in the following code, if someone can guide me to the right direction maybe it will be easier for me to get the same variable as in the else statement but manually (in case `FileReader` api isn't supported).

Basicly in my if statement I want to make an ajax call and transform the picture to the base64 string and save it to the read variable same structure as in my else statement:

```
    $('#file').on('change', function(){       

        if(typeof FileReader === "undefined") {
            //AJAX CALL HERE
        }
        else {
            var reader = new FileReader();
        }

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            options.imgSrc = e.target.result;
            cropper = $('.imageBox').cropbox(options);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        this.files = [];

        console.log(reader);
     })
```

console log for the read variable in the else statement shows: [Picture](http://shrani.si/f/1g/TO/r4JCOKa/untitled.png)

Comment: Little more clear. What you want to achieve? reader.readAsDataURL() will give you Base64 code and you can store that in String and pass to server using ajax.

Comment: No I want to send the picture to server and transform to Base64 there, then return the string back in the same format as reader.readAsDataURL()

Comment: Then your request should be of Multipart. Use <input type="file">

Comment: I am using that but that isn't the question, question is how can  I get the transformed base64 string in the same format in my if statement so that the function behaves the same as in else part

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without some kind of Polyfiller, the reason being that Javascript (without the FileReader API) cannot handle files and cannot pass them about. You will not be able to send the file to the server with Javascript.

There are 2 ways you can do this :

1. Cause a postback to occur in which you get the file on the server
   and then convert it to Base64 (can be done in PHP/ASP.NET (and
   probably lots of others))
2. Or you can use a Polyfiller such as
   [moxie](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie), this will load when the
   page loads and if File API is not supported it will add a
   Flash/Silverlight plugin to mimick the support.

Comment: how can I cause a postback to occur? I mean I did sent files to server before using ajax and `FormData` but do you have somethign else in mind?

Comment: What server side are you using? PHP/ASP.NET etc?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know PHP at all, so hopefully [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) can help you with that